# ios + Parse.com - Make table read-only

Tags: ios, swift, security, parse-platform

Today my app was hacked by someone. They filled 1k rows in my table. I guess that is happened because I don't use users for my app. In my AppDelegate I just have the following:

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId("...",
        clientKey: "...")

    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

How can I grant write access to some tables only for myself?

I dont want my app to have a login. I just want to make everyone instead of me a read-only users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set Parse to not allow data entry at all from the app - then data entry is only possible via the parse.com console in your browser. in Parse.com, go to `Settings -> General` and set the **Client class creation** to `No`.

Comment: I need it only for certain tables. And as far as I understand class is the table, but I want certain tables to be readonly.

Comment: Can't you only log in yourself in a special app version that does support login then and disallow create or modify of data by not-logged-in users?

Comment: I still want users to have write access to certain tables

Comment: Then give write access to not-logged-in users to those tables - however, you open those tables up for hacking again ...

Comment: Core -> Data -> <Your table>, you'll see the `Security` button in the top row of buttons

Comment: Ok I've found what I needed in the docs, thanks for the help anyway